# Is there a power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ example such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

The usual power series examples $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ in the Calculus texts always satisfy the fact that "$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ convergent". Is there an example of power series such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ **divergent**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Take $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigl(2+(-1)^n\bigr)x^n$, for instance.

Comment: Is there a name for these type of equations?

Comment: I wrote no equation.

Comment: I'd describe the $a_{n+1}/a_n$ sequence from this series as "oscillating".

Comment: How big is its radius of convergence? Btw, I ask this question because I want to find a concrete example that can not determine its convergence at any point by ratio test (which is a classic way texts always demonstrate), but we can know it has somehow a positive radius of convergence by theoretical reason.

Comment: The radius of convergence is $\sqrt{\frac13}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$$ for example.

Comment: How big is its radius of convergence? Can it be computed?